# PagedList.IPaged<ProjectName.WebUI.Model>does not contain a definition for Profiles(are you missing ising directive or refrence

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel, pagedlist

I am a new in Asp.net and i have one error in my view
i realised repository pattern in my project with Pagedlist and ViewModel

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HoboAnimal.Domain.Entities
{
    public class Profile
    {

        public int ProfileID { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public string PlaceHolder { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateOfPubl { get; set; }
        public string CurrentCategory { get; set; }

            }
}
```

My ViewModel class and controller:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using HoboAnimal.Domain.Entities;
using PagedList.Mvc;
using PagedList;

namespace HoboAnimal.WebUI.Models
{
    public class ProfilesListViewModel
    {

        public PagedList.IPagedList<Profile> Profiles {get; set;}

    }
}
```

And the view:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<HoboAnimal.WebUI.Models.ProfilesListViewModel>
    @using PagedList.Mvc;
    @using HoboAnimal.WebUI.Models


    <link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Profiles";
    }


    @foreach (var p in Model.Profiles)
    {


        <h2>@p.Image</h2>
        <h3>@p.DateOfPubl</h3>
        <h2>@p.CurrentCategory</h2>

    }

Страница @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) из @Model.PageCount

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }))
```

I have the error in this lane:

```
@foreach (var p in Model.Profiles)
```

> PagedList.IPagedList'
>   does not contain a definition for 'Profiles' and no extension method
>   'Profiles' accepting a first argument of type
>   'PagedList.IPagedList'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

I have no idea how to fix it, i tried to add @using directive in my model but it not helps
Thank U

Comment: You model is a collection of `ProfilesListViewModel` so it would need to be `@foreach (var m in Model) { foreach (var p in m.Profiles { .... } }` But is you model really `IPagedList<ProfilesListViewModel>` or should it be `@model ProfilesListViewModel`?

Comment: it should be IPagedList<ProfilesListViewModel> cause i want to use pagination

Comment: But your `Profiles` property of `ProfilesListViewModel` is `IPagedList<Profile>`. And having a paged list of another paged list makes no sense. Your model should be `@model ProfilesListViewModel` and then `@foreach (var p in Model.Profiles) { ... }` and finally `@Html.PagedListPager(Model.Profiles, page ....`

Comment: Thank u so much, your solution is working, i'm just messed with model, appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PagedList should be implemented somewhere similar to this. No need to create a view model for a PagedList.

**Controller**

```
using PagedList;

public ViewResult Index(int? page)
{
   var profiles = db.Profiles.ToList();

   int pageSize = 3;
   int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

   return View(profiles.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}
```

**View**

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<HoboAnimal.WebUI.Models.ProfilesListViewModel>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@using HoboAnimal.WebUI.Models

<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Profiles";
}

@foreach (var p in Model)
{
    <h2>@p.Image</h2>
    <h3>@p.DateOfPubl</h3>
    <h2>@p.CurrentCategory</h2>
}

<br />
Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", 
    new { page }))
```